# Positive Elements: Unique Decomposition

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

**Problem**

Given a C*-algebra $A$.

Define positive resp. negative part:
$$(\cdot)_\pm:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}:\quad2(x)_\pm:=|x|\pm x$$

> Then for commuting positive elements:
>   $$a_\pm\geq0:\quad a_\mp a_\pm=0\implies(a_+-a_-)_\pm=a_\pm$$
>   That is the decomposition is unique.

How can I prove this carefully?

**Attempt**

The issue I'm having here:

I can't just pull through the calculus:
$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}:\quad f(a+b)\neq f(a)+f(b)$$

Contrary Gelfand duality gives:
$$a_\pm\in\mathcal{C}^*(a_+,a_-)\cong\mathcal{C}(\Omega)$$
But the Gelfand spectrum is abstract.

So how can I check the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $a,b\geq0$ and $ab=0$. We have 
$$
(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2.
$$
By the uniqueness of the positive square root, it follows that 
$$
|a-b|=(a^2+b^2)^{1/2}=a+b.
$$
So
$$
2(a-b)_+=|a-b|+a-b=2a,
$$
$$
2(a-b)_-=|a-b|-(a-b)=2b.
$$

Comment: Nice, pretty hands-on, great! :D Thank you!!! :)